# Simple sequence a(n)

Tags: sequences-and-series

what is a sequence a(n) such that the nth entry of a(n) is {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,...,a(n)}, with the first entry pertaining to n=0, the second to n=1, ans

I attempted to use mathematica's FindSequenceFunction command:

FindSequenceFunction[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, n]

which did not return a functional answer.

Comment: $\text{floor}\lfloor x/7 \rfloor$?

Comment: What are restrictions on $a_n$? There are infinitely many sequences which start like this - you must have some criteria for picking out a given one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing:
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}
\lfloor\frac{n}{7}\rfloor\ \text {if}\ n<28\\
42\ \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
As Sten pointed out in a comment there are infinitely many sequences that start like yours, this is just one.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the obvious [A132270](https://oeis.org/A132270)(n-1), or [A054896](https://oeis.org/A054896)(n)

Comment: does there exist no closed form representation as a function of n?

Comment: For A132270(n-1), $$(n-3)/7 + \sum_r \dfrac{r^5+2 r^4+3 r^3+4 r^2+5 r-1}{49 r^{n+1}}$$ where the sum is over the roots $r$ of $X^6 + X^5 + X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1$.